# QAudioProbe is consuming excessive memory under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, audio, media-player

I am writing an mp3 player in Qt and I need to monitor my audio levels. To do this, I attach a QAudioProbe to my QMediaPlayer. However, when I do this in Windows, my memory consumption continuously increases. After about 3 hours of playing audio, my player exhausts all the memory on my machine and ceases to function.

Memory consumption is stable under OSX. It is also stable when attaching the audio probe to QAudioInput.

I've tried delete and deleteLater on my probe but this does not result in a reduction in memory usage according to the Task Manager. Are there any alternatives to QAudioProbe? I am quickly running out of ideas as to how to get around this memory issue.

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
player->setMedia(QUrl_to_my.mp3);

QAudioProbe *probe = new QAudioProbe(this);
probe->setSource(player); // Memory usage stabilizes if I comment this line out

player->play();
```

UPDATE: other things I have tried
QAudioDecoder - unfortunately, this seems to have the same memory leak. It's also not implemented under OSX.
Executing the code in a separate QThread - still leaks memory.

Comment: You don't need any alternatives, this simply seems to be a Qt bug. Report it.

Comment: In an ideal world, you'd be absolutely right. And I have filed a bug report. Unfortunately, I need my software to work now.

Comment: Then roll your own, it's relatively trivial to implement a peak program meter. Keep a running max of the absolute of the incoming samples.  When the next sample comes in if it's higher than the current max - set it as the new max. Otherwise decrease the max by `maxSampleValue * (sampleInterval / ppmDecayTime)`, the decay time for PPMs varies according to type but is usually about 1.7s to drop 20dB.  You should convert your running max to dB before displaying too.  Another way involves running the absolute signal through a low-pass filter, it's more efficient but more difficult to implement.

Comment: QAudioProbe is not a level monitor, all it does is return samples (audio buffers). My code is doing what you suggest. The problem is that the library used to get the samples is leaking memory. It would be nice to have a lightweight TagLib-esque cross-platform audio buffer access library (unfortunately, that's way beyond my coding abilities to make at this point).

Comment: How did you attach QAudioProbe to QAudioInput?